# Appending txt data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to append data from a txt file that looks like this:

```
Kit Kat|2 packets |Candy| 6
Flour|1 book|Book|2
```

I am trying to create a pandas DataFrame from this txt file with the column names: **name, quantity, category, ID.**

This is the code im currently using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Quantity', 'Category', 'ID'])

file = open("food.txt", "r")

for line in file:
   fields = line.split("|")
   product = df.append({'Name': fields[0]}, ignore_index=True)
   qty = df.append({'Quantity': fields[1]}, ignore_index=True)
   category= df.append({'Category': fields[2]}, ignore_index=True)
   ID = df.append({'ID': fields[3]}, ignore_index=True)

df.head()
```

I am getting an empty dataframe as a result, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use read_csv with **sep='|'** and **names=[COLUMNS_NAME]**

```
import pandas as pd

columns_name = ['Name', 'Quantity', 'Category', 'ID']
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='|', names=columns_name)

print(df)
```

file.txt

```
Kit Kat|2 packets |Candy| 6
Flour|1 book|Book|2
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Done! Thanks again. @bcosta12